# How can I model a snug mesh around a complex object?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, objects

I’m quite new to blender and I’d like to model some attachable camouflage like the one shown in this picture on to a vehicle.
[image]

Ideally I’d like it to be made from one mesh over the vehicle. In my head it is essentially a tea cosy for a tank.

Could anyone advise me on how to model it?

I will be using a cycles render engine

Edit: given some of the comments, I thought I'd add another picture that shows the 'tea cosy' after some wear and tear. It is close fitting, 'leafy' fabric camouflage that is attached to a tank.

[image]

Comment: is your computer strong enough to deal with particles / hair?

Comment: Why not just use a bump map or, if you must, a displacement map, and simply pretend that the camouflage material is a separate piece? Do you have an animation planned where this material needs to be visibly removed?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: So as Batfinger says I missed the coat thing, so it should probably be done with hair particles on a cloth, I'll try to rework my answer.

The first thing that comes to mind is to use a *Particle System > Hair*, with a leaf as object. Here is what it could give, with the *Particle System* settings: In *Render*, choose *Render As > Object*, and for *Instance Object* > choose the leaf object.

Give your leaf the same material as the tank hull, on the bottom of the *Texture Coordinate* node, don't forget to choose *Object > Tank* so that the leaves will take the color of the area where they are emitted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you make a netting object eg for body camo netting select faces, dupe faces, separate, extrude skirts (make cloth maybe) and add to that or just camo the tank material?

Comment: not sure what you mean, it doesn't look like a net, it rather looks like leaves sticked to the tank surface, no?

Comment: Yeah Sorry On close inspection it does look painted stuck on as you say.   Often this stuff is an elastic netting https://warisboring.com/the-u-s-army-is-repainting-its-tanks-green-hint-hint/  When looking at google images this popped up which is IMO is some pretty cool ol school modelling https://www.team-yankee.com/Default.aspx?tabid=909&art_id=5269

Comment: oh ok an elastic net makes sense, so I guess it could be done with the new pressure thing in the 2.8 cloth

Comment: lol too busy looking at the tank .. on question re-read  _" In my head it is essentially a tea cosy for a tank."_

Comment: yes I need to rework my answer

Comment: @moonboots , thanks very much for your suggestions. I'm going to have a go at them just now (even if it is just for some practice). I've added another picture to my question above to show how the fabric seems to look when it isn't brand new - shows a little more why I think it's like a tea cosy!

Comment: Hi @moonboots I've still not cracked this completely but am currently trying to do the hair particles on a 4 color camouflage pattern. Could you advise me what I should do with my materials settings to have the 'leaf' hair particles take on the color of the underlying texture?   Thanks!

Comment: I think it's only possible in Cycles and if your tank object has an Image Texture, not simple nodes, in that case you need to give your particles this node setup: Texture Coordinate with your tank as Object, enable the From Instancer option, use the UV output socket > plug into the Mapping node > Image Texture with the same image as the tank > Diffuse > Material Output